# Think you know Python RE? Here's a challenge

Tags: python, regex

Here's the skinny: how do you make a character set match NOT a previously captured character?

```
r'(.)[^\1]' # doesn't work
```

Here's the uh... fat? It's part of a (simple) cryptography program. Suppose "**hobo**" got coded to "**fxgx**". The program only gets the encoded text and has to figure what it could be, so it generates the pattern:

```
r'(.)(.)(.)\2' # 1st and 3rd letters *should* be different!
```

Now it (correctly) matches "**hobo**", but also matches "**hoho**" (think about it!). I've tried stuff like:

```
r'(.)([^\1])([^\1\2])\2' # also doesn't work
```

and *MANY* variations but alas! Alack...

Please help!

P.S. The work-around (which I had to implement) is to just retrieve the "**hobo**"s as well the "**hoho**"s, and then just filter the results (discarding the "**hoho**"s), if you catch my drift ;)

P.P.S Now I want a hoho

VVVVV THE ANSWER VVVVV

Yes, I *re*-re-read the documentation and it does say:

> Inside the '[' and ']' of a character class, all numeric escapes are
>   treated as characters.

As well as:

> Special characters lose their special meaning inside sets.

Which pretty much means (I think) NO, you can't do anything like:

```
re.compile(r'(.)[\1]') # Well you can, but it kills the back-reference!
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use a negative lookahead that contains the back-reference.

Comment: You're using wrong tool for the task. And it is wrong to put backreferences in the square brackets.

Comment: To match a string with all diferent letters, you should use a set and check the count of distinct chars. With regex, you may achieve it, but with an arbitrary number of chars is just an overkill. To match a word that starts with 3 different letters, use `re.match(r'([a-z])(?!\1)([a-z])(?!\1|\2)([a-z])', s)`

Comment: @Eugene Morozov Sir, I believe you are correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1st and 3rd letters *should* be different!

This cannot be detected using a regular expression (not just python's implementation). More specifically, it can't be detected using automata without memory. You'll have to use a different kind of automata.

The kind of grammar you're trying to discover (‫‪reduplication‬‬) is not regular. Moreover, it is not context-free.

**Automata** *is the mechanism which allows regular expression match to be so efficient.*

Comment: No sure what automata means, but you're right, can't do it with Python re

Comment: You can't do it with any implementation of regular expression. Not just Python.

Comment: @user1547581 Automata is the mechanism which allows regular expression match to be so efficient.